# Valor de input por defecto se borra

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

La siguiente línea me muestra un valor por defecto en el input:

```html
<input id="publication" name="publication" value="{{publication._id}}"/>
```

---

Pero al agregar el `[(ngMoldel)]="comment.publication"` para que guarde en la bd el input se pone vacío y si se hace clic en el botón guardar el campo `publication` me lo guarda vacío.

```html
<input id="publication" name="publication" value="{{publication._id}}" #text="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="comment.publication" />
```

Answer (score 0):

no es necesario ni recomendable que uses el atributo Value en el Input, si lo que desees es poblar el input al hacer un Update, eso lo hará la directiva ngModel, y recuerda importar en el archivo .ts de tu componente
lo siguiente:

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
```

y en tu app.module.ts lo siguiente para que puedas utilizar el NgForm:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: Gracias amigo ya lo solucione.